# MDX - calculating distinct count on date range

Tags: dax, mdx, iccube

i've got a cube (multidimensional) with

`[Person]`,
`[Arrival Date]` and
`[Departure Date]` dimensions,
`[Measures].[persons #D]` - distinct count of `[Person]`, and fact table containing dates of person's departures and arrivals.

I need to calculate distinct count of persons that "staying here" at user-picked date.
that mean i need count Persons that have `[Arrival Date]` before and `[Departure Date]` after user-picked date.

User selected date is stored in `[Measure].[EndOfPeriodDate]`.

In Dax/tabular model i can make it easy. something like that:

`CALCULATE(COUNTA([Person]); FILTER(FactTable;  ('FactTable'[Arrival Date] < [EndOfPeriodDate]) &&  'FactTable'[Departure Date] > [EndOfPeriodDate])))`

but i really can't understand how write the same in MDX (i'm working with icCube).

I wrote following measure and it works well:

`create  member [Measures].[PersonsAtEndOfPeriod] AS  aggregate ( NULL:[Arrival Date].[Arrival Date].[Day].lookupByName([measures].[EndOfPeriodDate])  ,[Measures].[Persons #D] )`

but its only first part. i need to add the second part of my condition

`([Departure Date].[Departure Date].[Day].lookupByName([measures].[EndOfPeriodDate]:NULL)`

i suppose it might be look like :

`NULL:[Arrival Date].[Arrival Date].[Day].lookupByName([measures].[EndOfPeriodDate]) +  ([Departure Date].[Departure Date].[Day].lookupByName([measures].[EndOfPeriodDate]:NULL)`

but it doesn't work...

QUESTION: how to add second (or more than 2) condition(s) in my measure?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First, the measure [Measures].[#People] should be a **distinct count** on the person unique id.

The definition should be:

```
WITH

   MEMBER toto as eval(SubCubeUnion(null:[Departure].[Departure].[Day].[3 Nov 2019],[Arrival].[Arrival].[Day].[8 May 2019]:null ), [Measures].[#People])

SELECT
   toto on 0
FROM [Cube]
```

Doc references:

- [SubCubeUnion](https://doc.iccube.com/?ic3topic=server.mdx.SubCubeUnion)
- [Eval](https://doc.iccube.com/?ic3topic=server.mdx.Eval)

Hope it helps!